# Solving limit with parameter $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sqrt{a^2+x}-|a|}{sin^{a}(2x)\cdot ln(cos(x))}$

Tags: calculus

Given the limit: $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sqrt{a^2+x}-|a|}{sin^{a}(2x)\cdot ln(cos(x))}$, with $a\in \mathbb{R}$, I would like to find the solutions of the limit with respect to the values of $a$.

I thought about using Taylor series to expand the functions, for example for $\sqrt{a^2+x}\sim \frac{1}{2}(a^2+x)^{-\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{1}{4}{(a^2+x)^\frac{-3}{2}}x+o(x^2)$, but it doesn't seem useful in this case.

Comment: You should start by doing a correct Taylor expansion. Make sure you also define $\sin^a(2x)$ correctly, and do the Taylor expansion of $\ln(\cos x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case $a=0$ is easy, so assume $a\ne0$.

Since
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(\sin2x)^a}{(2x)^a}=1
\qquad
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln(\cos x)}{x^2}=-\frac{1}{2}
$$
your limit can be computed as
$$
\lim_{x\to0}-2\frac{|a|(\sqrt{1+x/a^2}-1)}{(2x)^a x^2}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{|a|}{2^{a-1}}\frac{1-\sqrt{1+x/a^2}}{x^{a+2}}
$$
The numerator is $-x/(2a^2)+o(x)$.

Now, if $a=-1$, the limit is finite and nonzero; what if $a>-1$ or $a<-1$?